# Avoiding double instance of activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I've done a simple content based application. App always launch with splash screen. After 3 sec it goes to MainActivity from SpalshActivity. But am facing a problem. If i press back button when app showing splash screen and again launch the app from device app list then app start normally but then I have to press back icon twice to quit the app. Because app has another instance of MainActivity from previous launch.

How can I avoid this double instance ?

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}

 }
```

Comment: @JaredBurrows edited. Code has given

Comment: If you exit your application, this will run again if you hit the back button. If you hit the home button, if will resume your `MainActivity`. What is your issue?

Comment: An issue reported by QA and it is - If i press back button just at the moment app is launched and then again launch the app, app will run normally and after splash screen main activity will appear. But if I press back button then current mainactivity is gone but another instance of mainactivity still appear on screen. So I had to press back button twice to quit the app.

Comment: Post the source code for MainActivity and AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarise the symptoms first

- You launch the app.
- Press back while the splash screen is displayed
- Re-Launch the app which shows the splash screen followed by MainActivity
- **Press back which shows another MainActivity**
- Press back again which exits the app

The reason is that your postDelayed hander still runs even though you press back. Your phone is correctly starting `SplashActivity` but another `MainActivity` is being launched from the old `SplashActivity`.

You need to remove your `postDelayed` callback when you go into the background. Keep a reference to that `Handler` and call `removeCallbacksAndMessages`. I would normally start `postDelayed` in `onResume` and remove it in `onPause`

Alternatively you can launch `MainActivity` with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag. That flag indicates that if `MainActivity` already exists in the back stack it should be brought to the front and activities above it should be closed. You can also add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` if you want it to re-use the same activity instance instead of creating a new one.

Comment: thnx for explanation. Its clear to me now. It will be solved definitely .

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest.xml, add for the `MainActivity`:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

When you launch your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: what if you specify the xml and not in the code via intent? does it matter?

Comment: @ZakTaccardi It doesn't matter point is it should be available

Answer (score 0):

let me give you my way of avoiding this error :

add this before your " super.onCreate(null);" in your onCreate method

```
if (!isTaskRoot()
                && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                && getIntent().getAction() != null
                && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

super.onCreate(null);
```

It will finish the splashactivity whenever it is called while it wasnt the taskroot.

Second option is to get rid of the postdelayed, which is the function that messes the process.

Answer (score 0):

This method can cause to open twice:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

I solved my problem by deleting this.